# How To Return A Struct From A Function In C++

Tags: c++, pointers, loops, struct

So I've thoroughly gone through the topics by searching this site but I couldn't find something which can help me.

I'm making a task for my friend and let me tell you that it's been a year or more since I've used C++.

So the problem I'm facing is with pointers and returning struct through pointer.

Here's the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

    struct student
   {
    int SUB[3];
   };

   struct AVGPCT
   {
    float avg;
      float pct;
   };


AVGPCT* CALC(student *A)
{
   int x,y;
    AVGPCT D[5]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};

   for(x=0;x<5;x++)
   {
    for(y=0;y<3;y++)
      {
        D[x].avg+=A[x].SUB[y];
         D[x].pct+=A[x].SUB[y];
      }
   }

   for(x=0;x<5;x++)
   {
    D[x].avg/=2;
      D[x].pct/=300;
   }
   return (D);
}

void main(void)
{
   int i,j;
   student S[5];
   AVGPCT *V;

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      {
        cout << "Enter Marks Of Subject[" << (j+1) << "] Of Student [" << (i+1) <<"] [Max=100]:";
        cin >> S[i].SUB[j];
      }
   }

   V = CALC(S);
   cout << "Average Number Of Student [1]: " << V->avg;
   cout << (*V).pct;

   getch();
}
```

Now the problem is, it is giving me a hard time to retrieve correct values from the location.

I'm trying to increment the pointer with V++. The funny thing is it is printing the values correctly if I use:

```
cout << V->avg;
cout << V->pct;
V++;
cout << V->avg;
cout << V->pct;
```

And so on. But if I use loop or write even a single line or use endl or \n, the values jumble up and gibberish values appear.

So what could be going wrong here?

It is important that I use struct and also please guide according to the code.

Comment: So you want advice, but.. you don't want advice?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, what I meant was not to tear down my code and suggest/advice completely different thing.

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Make sure you are using small, well named functions, and spaces around operators. Your indentation is off in places too. 

Also, you should really only be using `#include <iostream>`, no need for .h There is no need for the C headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this line

```
AVGPCT D[5]={0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0};
```

declares the array D locally to the function `CALC()`

You pass a pointer to that array back to the main function, but the array is marked as free game for overwriting when the function ends. The more stuff you do in the program, the more chance there is of this location in memory being overwritten, though it's hard to say when that will happen. Hence, sometimes you get away with it, other times you don't.

At the risk of giving you advice, it's probably better to declare `D` somewhere in main and pass a pointer to it into the function or use a `new` or `malloc` inside the function and pass the resultant pointer back.

Comment: Thanx mate, I completely overlooked that I was declaring it locally in the function.

Solved it. :)

Comment: No problem, @MajorAly, that'll happen. If this solved things for you, feel free to make it your accepted answer. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Returning a pointer to data on the stack doesn't work. Use a `std:vector<AVGPCT>` instead and return it by value, not by pointer. C++ is, unlike Java or C#, based on values rather than pointers.

C++ doesn't allow returning `void` from `main()`.

The header `<iostream.h>` doesn't exist according to the C++ standard. The standard header is `<iostream>`.